# Object location based on screen coordinates in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, game-engine

I am an amateur programmer trying to making a game in python and pygame (I know, not the best, but I know how to use it better than Java and C++).  I came across an interesting problem: locating a specific sprite onscreen using screen coordinates, and then moving that sprite to a different location.
For example, I have an inventory, and I'm coding in a way for the player to drop an item out of their inventory, back onto the two dimensional playing field so the player can pick it up later.
As there will be a varying amount of items, it is sort of inefficient to tack *all* their coordinates to a list and try to manage it that way. It just gets too messy trying to connect the constantly changing item list to the objects on field.

I have attached the code I have so far in case that helps. I've looked online but haven't found any suggestions on how to do this, and the only other solution I've found would be to somehow find the object using `spritecollide()` and an invisible sprite, but I'd need help for that.

The drop function is the part I'm working on now. `pos()` is a list of 2 items, `x` and `y`, which are the mouse coordinates of where you click on the screen.

The class that creates the inventory:

```
import pygame
from testRect import *

class Inventory(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Define colors
    white = (255,255,255)
    dgreen = (0,154,0)#useables
    dblue = (0,0,154)#throwables
    dred = (154,0,0)#holdables

    def __init__(self,surface,pos,grid,gridItems,handsUsed):
        for row in range(4):
        # Add an empty array that will hold each cell
        # in this row
        grid.append([])
        for column in range(4):
            grid[row].append(0) # Append a cell
        gridItems.append([])
        for column in range(4):
            gridItems[row].append(0) # Append a cell
        self.update(surface,pos,grid,gridItems,handsUsed)

    def update(self,surface,pos,grid,gridItems,handsUsed):
        width=40
        height=40
        margin=2
        #convert click location to grid squares
        column=pos[0] // (width+margin)-20
        row=pos[1] // (height+margin)-7
        #make grid selection (toggle if selected or not)
        if row >-1 and row <4 and column >-1 and column < 4:
            if grid[row][column] == 0 and handsUsed < 2:
                grid[row][column] = 1
                handsUsed += 1
            elif grid[row][column] == 1 and handsUsed > 0:
            grid[row][column] = 0
            handsUsed -= 1
        # Draw the grid and determine type of object
        for row in range(4):
            for column in range(4):
                color = self.white
                if grid[row][column] == 1 and gridItems[row][column] == 1:
                    color = self.dgreen
                elif grid[row][column] == 1 and gridItems[row][column] == 2:
                    color = self.dblue
                elif grid[row][column] == 1 and gridItems[row][column] == 3:
                    color = self.dred
                pygame.draw.rect(surface,color,[((margin+width)*column+margin)+840,((margin+height)*row+margin)+295,width,height])

        return handsUsed#return the variable so that the master handsUsed var will also update

    def drop(self,pos,handsUsed,grid,staticsprites):
        moved = False
        if pos[0] > 838 and pos[0] < 1011 and pos[1] > 491 and pos[1] < 538 and handsUsed > 0:
            width=40
            height=40
            margin=2
            row = 0
            column = 0
            while row < 4 and moved == False:
                if grid[row][column] == 1:
                    #items selected will set their coordinates to a space near the player.
                    #Will check to see if spot is open in this priority (high to low): below, above, left, right
                    #finds the item to be moved
                    itemSelectRow = row * (((height + margin)-7))+299
                    itemSelectColumn = (column * ((width + margin)+20))+845
                    collideList = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(testRect, staticsprites, False)
                    if collideList != None:
                        #will move the item to the location since nothing is in the way
                        print collideList
                    moved = True
                    break
                elif row < 4 and column < 3:
                    print "hi"
                    column += 1
                elif row < 4 and column >= 3:
                    column = 0
                    row += 1
                else:
                    break
        return handsUsed#return the variable so that the master handsUsed var will also update
```

Comment: Have you a "Item" class and a Item list which persists all item objects? I don't really understand your code, it really have meaningless constants everywhere. In my opinion, maybe Items should not be "dropped" onto map that hard, at least not in "Inventory" code. collision tests could be done on "Item" object creation time, to just test on existing items.

Comment: All of the items are stored in a group called `staticsprites`. Should I somehow use that to test which item should be moved?

Answer (score 0):

Ok them, I thought you were dragging the item outside the inventory window, like minecraft for example but nvm.

Them you click the "drop" button, you get the player.position and test the 8 fields around the player if you can really drop in one of these fields, when you find a empty place, you drop and add the item with its position to a list of dropped items.

```
class DroppedItem:
    def __init__(item_type,x,y):
        self.itype = item_type
        self.pos = [x,y]

#you have one list with all dropped items in the map
DROPPED = []
#Them, inside your function code when you drop the item:
DROPPED.append(DroppedItem(itype,x,y))
#itype is the type of item, best use IDs #1=swordx,2=bow of death,....33=holy arrow
#x and y is the position in the ground.
```

I recommend you to be familiar with Classes and Object-oriented programming (OOP)
since it allows you to write much cleaner and efficient codes.
Sorry my bad english.

Comment: The camera doesn't move. This is more of a room-based game. You look top-down on a map, and your player moves around on the map independently. There are doors at the edges of the map for you to move on to the next room, but each room is independent of each other. To drop an item, you select the item from your inventory, and then press a "drop" button, which moves it onto the field next to the player. Does that make a little more sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need someway to put the Item to the ground and as close to player as possible, and you need some way to try out possible positions to do the item dropping. Am I right?

I've one year python exp and a few exp in game programming.

Here is the thing:

game programming is not science, you might find an easier way to do this at first, and do it better when the game shapes up. I don't know how your game looks like, but I think how items scattered (may be you are thinking about Diablo2 Item dropping or something?) on the ground is not the sweet-spot of most games. you can just do collision tests with logical map matrix with simple x, y grid, instead of some compute-intense sprite collision test.

Make it simple enough so that you can handle it, you can remember what the code does after a few weeks(or years), too complex stuff hurts.

good luck and make a great game :)